# How can I make the option's of the select boxes to push the other select boxes down when they open

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, tailwind-css, navbar

I want the options push down other code when they open but it is not working

```html
<select className="text-2xl text-black mt-8 border-b-2 border-grey pb-3 " title={<><TfiServer className="inline-block w-fit" /> سرور ها</>} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
  <option className=""> <Link to="/t">سرور ها</Link></option>
  <option className=""><Link to="/">اضافه کردن سرور جدید</Link></option>
</select>
<select className="text-2xl text-black mt-8 border-b-2 border-grey pb-3 " title={<><SlWrench className="inline-block w-fit" /> کانفیگ ها</>} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
  <option className=""><Link to="/">کل کانفیگ ها</Link> </option>
  <option className=""><Link to="/">ایجاد کانفیگ جدید</Link></option>
  <option className=""><Link to="/">مشاهده ی لاگ های کانفیگ</Link></option>
</select>
<select className="text-2xl text-black mt-8 border-b-2 border-grey pb-3 " title={<><MdOutlineHomeRepairService className="inline-block w-fit" /> سرویس های من </>} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
  <option className=""> <Link to="/">لایسنس ها</Link></option>
  <option className=""> <Link to="/">سرویس های بک آپ</Link></option>
  <option className=""><Link to="/">سرویس های LookUp</Link></option>
  <option className=""><Link to="/">سفارش سرویس جدید</Link></option>
  <option className=""><Link to="/">انتقال لایسنس از اکانت دیگر</Link></option>
</select>
```

I have tried to give them `display: block` or `position: relative` but still doesn't work. I have tried it with `bootstrap` navbar components and it was okay, but now that I am trying to do it with `html` tag and `tailwind`, it doesn't work.

Comment: That's not how native `select` elements work, you will need a custom replacement-

Comment: Also, `option` elements can contain text only; you can not stick links in there.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will show the content between the opening `<option>` and closing `</option>` tags in a drop-down list. The value of the value attribute, on the other hand, is what is delivered to the server when a form is submitted.

So, you cannot stick with `"/"` in your `options` tag.

Other than that it is good to go.